# program stuck at the end of recursion in (recursive)insertion sort

Tags: c++, recursion, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement insertion sort recursively in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> insertionSort(vector<int>& A,int p,int r)
{ 
    for(auto x=p;x<=r;++x) cout<<A[x]<<' ';
    cout<<endl;  
    if(p<r-1) insertionSort(A,p,r-1);
    cout<<"flag";
    int key=A[r];
    int i=r-1;
    while(i>p)
    {
        if(key<=A[i])
        {
            A[i+1]=A[i];
            i=i-1;
        }
        A[i+1]=key;
    }
    return A;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> A {22,2,31,41,59,90,11,26,41,58};
    insertionSort(A,0,A.size()-1);
    for(auto x:A) cout<<x<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Output:

22 2 31 41 59 90 11 26 41 58 
22 2 31 41 59 90 11 26 41 
22 2 31 41 59 90 11 26 
22 2 31 41 59 90 11 
22 2 31 41 59 90 
22 2 31 41 59 
22 2 31 41 
22 2 31 
22 2 
^C⏎

As u can see it gets stuck at the end of recursion(it doesn't go past the *flag* statement) and i've to manually quit the execution. If my understanding is correct, when the recursion reaches its end the next statements are executed in each of the call stacks. Please help me figure out the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the base case? Do you mean to `return` the result of the recursive call to insertionSort?

Comment: Begin with a smaller vector, and then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Note that putting statements on different lines helps.

Comment: @drescherjm nothing. once it reaches the end the next statements are supposed the insert the A[r] to it's appropriate place. so the array gets sorted from left to right. insertion in every step takes from right to left.

Comment: in the while loop key > A[i] leads to an endless loop because i never changes.

Comment: You likely aren't seeing the 'flag' because of buffering. Try `cout << "flag" << flush;`

Comment: @ChristianO. why is key > A[i]? it's an unsorted array. and i does change. i=i-1 in the if block.

Comment: @Kevin thnx.now flag is printed twice.

Comment: Debugger! Debugger! Debugger!!!

Comment: @Debasis_Buxy _"and i does change. i=i-1 in the if block."_ Only if `key <= A[i]`. If it's not, you have an infinite loop. As was already stated.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i will look for some tutorials. i dont know how to use it.

Comment: Then this is an excellent time to learn. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the helpful comments. Like they said, the program appeared to be stuck due an infinite loop which occured when the `if` block was not executed. So I added a `break` and also put the insertion statement outside the `while` block. Here's the corrected code:

```
vector<int> insertionSort(vector<int>& A,int p,int r)
{   
    if(p<r-1) insertionSort(A,p,r-1);
    int key=A[r];
    int i=r-1;
    while(i>=p)
    {
        if(key<A[i])
        {
            A[i+1]=A[i];
            i=i-1;
        }
        else break;
    }
    A[i+1]=key;
    return A;
}
```